# 'Group by' in Kibana charts

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new to both Elasticsearch and Kibana, so this might be really simple so solve. I'm trying to summarize some data and display it in a simple Line Chart in Kibana, but having a hard time getting the result i want.

My data looks like this:

```
{"name": "Q1", "indexing_date": "2019-11-11T09:00:00", "items_in_queue": 2}
{"name": "Q2", "indexing_date": "2019-11-11T09:00:00", "items_in_queue": 3}
{"name": "Q1", "indexing_date": "2019-11-11T09:00:25", "items_in_queue": 2}
{"name": "Q2", "indexing_date": "2019-11-11T09:00:25", "items_in_queue": 4}
{"name": "Q3", "indexing_date": "2019-11-11T09:07:00", "items_in_queue": 1}
{"name": "Q2", "indexing_date": "2019-11-11T09:07:00", "items_in_queue": 3}
```

I want a Date Histogram (on "indexing_date") as the X-Axis, and a Sum (on "items_in_queue") on the Y-axis. With the example data above, the result would be 3 points with the sum 5, 6 and 4.

It works, but when I change the time period displayed in the chart, the first two points are merged together and displayed as one (with the value 5 + 6 = 11). Is it possible to force Kibana to "group by" a field ("indexing_date" in this case)? All documents included in each sum have the same "indexing_date".

If it makes it easier I have the possibility to change the layout of the documents.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

While creating `Date Histogram` Aggregation, the interval is set to `auto` by default. You have to explicitly set the interval to `Second`. And you will have the visualization you want. Check out the screen below.

[image: set the interval to Second]

Comment: The "interval" you're refering to shows up as "Minimum interval" in my version of Kibana (7.4.0). If I enter "Second" in there, and changes the time period displayed in the chart to 8:55 -> 9:10, the text "Currently scaled to 5 seconds" shows up. The graph looks correct, with the exception that the scale of the Y-axis is completely off. At 9.00 the value is 1, 9.00.25 has the value of 1.2 and 9:07 has the value 0.8.

If I change the "Minimum interval" to 15s, the chart looks ok with the same time span as above. But if I Change to 8:55->10:00 the graph only has two values (5.5 and 2).

Comment: you will have to set the time filter to lesser range. For example, `last 5 minutes` or even lesser than that. 
Another approach is to select `visual builder` visualization. There, in `panel options` tab, set appropriate `index pattern`, `Time Field` and set `Interval` to `1s`. While doing all this, make sure that your global time filter has a range of `last 5 minutes` or even lesser range.